# Avoid to apply functions on the indexed column

Tags: mysql

Asume table A in MySQL 5.7, with index on the column `name`:
id name
1   Alice
2   Nancy
...

Now finding out names with length greater than 5.
The query is:

```
select * from A where length(name) >= 5;
```

However, if applying functions on column with index, then the index will not work.
So how to optimize the query to hit the index?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, MySQL 8+ finally supports functional indices, so you may add the following index here:

```sql
ALTER TABLE A ADD INDEX((LENGTH(name)));
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, you would need to get more creative.  On MySQL 5.7, you could have added a new column `name_length` to the `A` table.  When you insert a name, also insert the length, and then index the length column:

```sql
INSERT INTO A (name, name_length)
VALUES
    ('Gordon', 6);

CREATE INDEX idx ON A (name_length);

SELECT * FROM A WHERE name_length >= 5;
```

Comment: For earlier versions indexed generated column may help.

Comment: Even without that, it will likely use the index (reading the entire index rather than the entire table)